# Sprite Kit and Swift, increasing the speed of a node over time?

Tags: ios, swift, skaction

I have a wall that generates and then moves Left (Pulls) and I'm curious on if I can somehow make it so that overtime it gets faster and faster. Is this possible?

Here is the code I'm using to pull the "wall":

```
func startMoving() {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: 0.35)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
}
```

This is what Generates the walls in case you need to know:

```
var generationTimer: NSTimer?

func startGeneratingWallsEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
    generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateWall", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This line of code is what starts the generator

```
wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(0.5)
```

everything works, but I want to know how to make it so it starts off slow then gets faster overtime (makes it harder).

Comment: Do you mean the speed of each wall should increase as it moves across the screen? Or as the user is playing the game gets harder by increasing the speed they're moving at?

Comment: @ABakerSmith sorry I've been away, and I mean as the user is playing the game gets harder as it increases the speed

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a variable for the duration of the action and keep a counter that increments every time a wall is pulled. After a certain number of walls have been moved (5 in this example), you can reduce the duration by a certain amount.

```
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.35
var counter: NSUInteger = 0

func startMoving(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: duration)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))

    counter += 1
    if counter % 5 == 0 {
        duration -= 0.01
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what will happen if the SKAction duration is negative, so you may need to guard against that.